# How can I read a hard drive's factory serial number from a Java program?

Tags: java

I want to read a hard disk's factory serial number, not the volume serial number from a Aava program or C or C++ if this isn't possible in Java.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Win32_PhysicalMedia** class with the **SerialNumber** property to obtain that.

A quick Google search came up with this [already written program to do exactly that.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/hard_disk_serialno.aspx)

It works just like a SQL Query on a table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to access WMI (windows management interface) from Java.

From quick googling try this [solution](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/other_examples/WMI_Scripting_from_Java.htm).
Or maybe this open source [one](http://jawinproject.sourceforge.net/jawin.html).

Check out [this](http://groovy.codehaus.org/COM+Scripting) for Groovy based solution.